# How to graft and backout in one command?

Tags: mercurial

Every now and then someone on my team will commit & push a changeset to the wrong branch. I've been looking for the easiest way to move these changesets to the proper branch. There are many options: exporting diffs + reverting, grafting + backing out, transplanting, rebasing.

Grafting seems to be the closest to what I want, but I also need to remove the changesets from their original branch. Is there any command that does both? "rebasing" sounds like it would fit the bill, but it doesn't work after the changes have been pushed. Ideally this would work with multiple changesets.

Comment: Rebasing is *not* equivalent to graft + backout.  Rebasing will remove the offending revision from (your copy of) history, while backout will create a new revision that exactly undoes the previous revision.  Backout is safe for public changesets, but rebase is not.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 'Mercurial evolution' enabled for all your users and central repository, you could actually do a rebase on already-pushed changes. However, you probably don't want to edit public history, right?

The only other alternative I can think of would be an alias that executes both commands.

Comment: If the commits are public, you would not be able to, unless you forced the phase of the public changeset to draft.  That way lies madness.

Comment: That's indeed what I meant. However, if all of the repositories of his users and the central repository  were non-publishing, he could do sorcery like this. It's worth mentioning at least :-)